# What we call a collections of sets contained in an open ball? Uniformly bounded sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Consider a collection of sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n,\ldots$ in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Then, can we call these sets uniformly bounded if $A_i \subset {\cal B}(a, r)$ ($i \in \{1,\ldots\}$)? Note that ${\cal B}(a, r)$ is an open ball centered at $a$ and with radius $r$. Thanks!

Comment: If $a,r$ does not depend on $i$ then yes

Comment: @BAI Thanks very much for your answer. Yes, they are independent of $i$. Which book/paper could I choose as a reference? Thanks :-)